# $\mathscr{H}^{n-2}(\Sigma)< \infty$ implies $\mathscr{H}^{n-1}(\pi(\Sigma))=0$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Let $\Sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a set with $(n-2)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure finite, i.e. $\mathscr{H}^{n-2}(\Sigma)<\infty$. Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the projection on the first $n$ coordinates. In a paper I am reading it is claimed that then $\mathscr{H}^{n-1}(\pi(\Sigma))=0$, but there is no proof of this fact. Any hints on how it can be proved?

Comment: Do you mind giving the kernel you use for the 2 capacity, I guess you mean Newtonian but just to be sure.

Comment: @an_ordinary_mathematician my definition of $2$-capacity is the one used by Evans in his book "Measure theory and fine properties of functions". That is, $\operatorname{Cap}_2(E)=\inf\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|D\eta|^2 \,|\, $ where $\eta\in L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is $\geq 1$ on $E$ and $D\eta\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$.

Comment: As stated this looks a bit odd. For example, every line in $\mathbf{R}^3$ has two-capacity zero. In particular, this is true for say $\{ x_2 = 0 = x_3 \}$, but projecting this onto the plane $\{ x_3 = 0 \}$ one gets a line still, so something with infinite $\mathcal{H}^1$-measure. Are you missing some hypotheses?

Comment: @LeoMoos Thank you very much for your comment. Of course your counterexample shows that what I had initially claimed in the body of the question cannot be true. I realised that the issue was that in the setting of the paper the word "capacity" refers to the capacity in a $n$-dimensional manifold $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and not to the usual capacity in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. I have thus edited the question by assuming $\mathscr{H}^{n-2}(\Sigma)<\infty$ instead of $Cap_2(\Sigma)=0$.

Comment: Projection is 1-Lip map, thus does not increase the Hausdorff measure and Hausdorff dimension

Comment: @FedorPetrov Oh my, sure, I don't know how I couldn't see it. Then we get $\mathscr{H}^{n-2}(\pi(\Sigma))<\infty$ and hence in particular $\mathscr{H}^{n-1}(\pi(\Sigma))=0$. Thanks.